# Why this Sketchfab model isn't relighting?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I got a [room model from Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/the-billiards-room-79615d823a9149069dcd06c20bc9707f) but my attempts to relight it so far failed. The model is not reacting to a point light inserted inside the room nor to the World Shader emission. I'm sure it's something silly I've overlooked but for the life of me I can't figure it out.
I also tried restoring factory defaults and importing the same model, but got the same result.
Not all Sketchfab models behave like that so I'm suspecting it's something in the object settings.

Attached is a .blend file - I've joined all separate room objects, decimated it and reduced texture to 4k to keep the size down.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The billiard room is one mesh object with one image texture. The image texture has **baked lighting** and is shown by an ***Emission* shader node** as you can see in the *Shader Editor* when you inspect the material.

Objects with an *Emission* shader [don't receive shadows](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/156646/107598) and this material basically turns the whole room into a light source. Such material is used in mobile games or when you don't need dynamic lights.

[image: screenshot 1]

For dynamic lights, replace the *Emission* shader node with a *Diffuse* shader node and increase the *Power* of the *Point* light. The room seems larger than it would be in real scale so you need more light power. Try 2000 W.

Note, you can not extinguish the candles, because the light is baked in. To remove the candlelight, you need to paint over the texture image.

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Oh, wow. I did notice that the whole room is an emission shader, but did not click (and actually not read before) that such objects cannot receive shadows, though now it makes perfect sense. Thanks for the answer. Problem solved!